# Variable " asset_url" does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig, theming

Not sure what's wrong but I can't include javascript and/or stylesheet files. Using Symfony3

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@AppBundle/assets/js/jquery.js'
        '@AppBundle/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

getting this error:
Variable " asset_url" does not exist in security/login.html.twig at line 32

Comment: Could you try to add `output='js/compiled/app.js'` at the end of (and inside of it) `javascripts`? It would be just above `<script>` The reason why I think that this could solve the problem is because `asset_url` would be compiled file from `output`

Comment: `{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts output='js/compiled/app.js'` no luck yet

Comment: Where are your files located?  They are typically in `@AppBundle/Resources/public` instead of `@AppBundle/assets`

Answer (score 0):

Overall, the code should probably look like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@AppBundle/assets/js/jquery.js'
        '@AppBundle/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        output='js/compiled/app.js' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

If it doesn't work then make sure that path to these files is correct.

Comment: well, lets make it simple, i should use just js/<file>.js if they are in web folder ?

Comment: Yes. For example `'js/jquery.js'` or `'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'` (if it also is in the web folder and has such structure)

Comment: `{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts output='js/compiled/app.js'
    'js/jquery.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}

        {% endblock %}` I have now and triple checked the jquery.js file exists in web/js/ folder

Comment: Try to move output to the end of `javascripts` as I did

Comment: Try to move it outside of the block and see if anything changes

Comment: no luck, when I do `{% block javascripts %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}` it loads page correctly, but when I see source and try to open the file, its empty, so I think It can't find the file. It's placed in web/js/jquery.js

Comment: I assume that you run it with built-in Web Server, does it have permission to access all of these files? Because I suspect that problem lies somewhere else, as my code should load these assets without any problems.

Comment: it should have permissions, tho if u know what per folder need I can check, it can write cache etc tho...

Comment: I have now     `{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts
    'js/jquery.js'
     output='js/compiled/app.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}

        {% endblock %}` and there is app_jquery_1.js in web/js/compiled/ folder (it was app.js before but I renamed it). I used php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod to dumb these. Don't know whats wrong but I can't get JS or CSS to work with symphony